# C# clear listview columns cells

Tags: c#, listview, cell

I have some columns in listview which are "Column1", "Column2",....
I want to clear (set null character at that cells) and remove some cells from related columns which can be (1.column) "Column1".Could you help me?

Specific question:
After selected rows deleted, I want to update my ID column with updated numbers with a button. How can I do that?

[image: http://hizliresim.com/ydaAP0]

```
for (int i = 1; i <= newID; i++)
{
    int newID = listView1.Items.Count;
    listView1.Items[0].Remove(listView1.Columns[0].ListView.Items.Count); // something like that ?
    listView1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I could not upload image because of rep

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to delete some rows in the middle and give the later ones their id? (e.g. you have 3 rows -> delete row number 2 -> row number 3 id is now 2)

Comment: Yes. In order to 0-2-4-6-7-8-9>>>1-2-3-4-5-6-7. Only I want to change column1 in listview1

Comment: Hmm, am I the only one that doesn't really understand the question?

Comment: sorry I could not understand you? maybe I could not ask clearly.what did u not understand?

Answer (score 0):

After some modicifation with others code u can get what you want with button.

```
 if (listView1.Items.Count == 0) return;
            var col = listView1.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>()
                                .Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
                                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.x.Text == "ID");
            if (col == null) return;
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                item.SubItems[col.i].Text = "";
            }
            int newID = listView1.Items.Count;
            for (int i = 1; i <= newID; i++)
            {
                listView1.Items[i-1].SubItems[0].Text = i.ToString();
            }
```